# Can anyone help me consolidate these IIS rewrite rules?

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I've got some IIS rewrite rules in place, and everything is working fine. But i feel like i can consolidate them.

Here are my rules:

```
<rule name="Blog - Advice - root" patternSyntax="ExactMatch" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="advice" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="https://mysite.wpengine.com/advice" />
</rule>

<rule name="Blog - Advice - root (with slash)" patternSyntax="ExactMatch" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="advice/" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="https://mysite.wpengine.com/advice" />
</rule>

<rule name="Blog - Advice" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^advice/?(.*)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="https://mysite.wpengine.com/advice/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

I want to match the following examples:

- `/advice`
- `/advice/` (should rewrite without the slash)
- `/advice/sdfsdf`
- `/advice/sdfsdf/` (should rewrite without the slash)
- `/advice/sdfdsf/sdfds`

Can it be done with 1 (or 2) routes?

If i leave the second one out for example, Wordpress (the site i'm rewriting to), will do a 301 redirect to a URL *without* the slash, and i lose the rewrite since the URL is changed again. (so i end up at `mysite.wpengine.com/advice`, which is wrong).

So i need to make sure any rewrites don't involve a redirect on the target site end.

Many thanks :)